# NDK xlocale.h exception

Tags: android, android-ndk, live555

Trying to load live555 library but having following error when I do ndk-build

```
Compile++ thumb  : live555 <= Locale.cpp
In file included from jni/live555/Locale.cpp:22:0:
/Volumes/Projects/Ayaz_Projects/streamer/./jni/live555/include/Locale.hh:47:123: fatal error: xlocale.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/live555/Locale.o] Error 1
```

xlocale.h is nowhere in the live555 code

What should I do?

Comment: hmmm you should use google ... http://bit.ly/W7IGIe

Answer (score 1):

The include file has the following:

```
#ifndef LOCALE_NOT_USED
#include <locale.h>
#ifndef XLOCALE_NOT_USED
#include <xlocale.h> // because, on some systems, <locale.h> doesn't include <xlocale.h>; this makes sure that we get both
#endif
#endif
```

So you should be able to add `-DXLOCALE_NOT_USED` to your `Android.mk` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I got here seearching for `xlocale.h not found` (unrelated to android development). My solution was https://serverfault.com/a/791822/394721